# Xcode Build and Run Succeeds, but Archive Fails

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

My app builds and runs successfully, but archives fails, therefore I can't make an ipa file. Error log is following:

`ld: library not found for -lAAMFeedback
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

the library is this:
pod 'AAMFeedback', :git => 'https://github.com/PlusR/AAMFeedback.git'

Anyone encountered the same situation before? Please share the experience to help me. Thanks,

version info:
Xcode version: 7.3.1
target ios version: 8.0

Comment: What I've tried( and nothing worked)
1: Adding AAMFeedback.a to Link Binary With Libraries,
2: version up AAMFeedback(0.4.0 -> 0.5.0),
3: delete Pods/ and re-install pod

Answer (score 6):

I finally managed to Archive. It was the reason why archive didn't succeed to set Product > Edit Scheme > Build setting. I unchecked 'Find implicit Dependencies' during development, which fasten the building process. However it is needed to check that setting when archiving.

[image]

Comment: This was my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**Xcode 9.0**

For me what works was to go **Product > Scheme > Manage Scheme** and tick all the checkboxes, then **Build again** and then **Archive**.

Hopefully, this can help someone else.

Comment: left side or right side check boxes which one I should check, please reply quickly

Comment: @RahulKRajan I tried both combination, none worked

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the AAMFeedback in your Link Binary with Libraries under the Build Phases, try adding your Library's framework there

Comment: Already tried  adding AAMFeedback.a to Link Binary With Libraries, but it didn't work.

Comment: Read your comment on what you have tried, if none of these worked, try importing the AAMFeedback as static library